# The same value, 16, was passed as the prevKey in two sequential Pages loaded from a PagingSource

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging

I have this pager with Paging 3 that keeps either repeating pages (if I allow keyReuseSupported) or returning the IllegalStateException because of "The same value, 16, was passed as the prevKey in two sequential Pages loaded from a PagingSource." I am not sure why this is happening, even if I do understand the theory.

This is the paging data source:

```
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, CameraManagerEvent> {
       val key = params.key ?: parseDateFrom(date)
     
       return runCatching {
          service.getEvents(
                   dateJump = this.date,
                   one = true
               )
           }
       }.fold(
           onFailure = { LoadResult.Error(it) },
           onSuccess = {
               LoadResult.Page(
                   data = it.events,
                   prevKey = if(date>18) null else parseDate(date) + 1, 
                   nextKey = if(it.events.isEmpty()) null else parseDate(date) - 1
               )
           }
       )
   }
```

When I send for example date 15, the prevKey is 16, the nextKey is 17, but it seems to return 16 twice... why is the prevKey and the nextKey not working properly? I need to be able to return the next and previous date with my paging but if I do this:

```
prevKey = if(date>18) null else key + 1, 
nextKey = if(it.events.isEmpty()) null else key - 1
```

It just keeps returning the same two pages (16 and 17 for example). What's going on?